# Did I purchase the correct brakes for my Huffy bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, brakes, pads

Did I purchase the correct bike brakes for my Huffy bicycle.  I just put the back set on the back and no matter how hard I squeeze the brake it is not tight enough to stop bike.

If anyone know please help thanks.

[image]

Comment: Depends on the type of brake, there are several, it could be a cantilever, BMX style U brake, or a V-brake. These pads looks to be for an old school U brake. The other issue could be the brake cable tension. After riding and using the brakes for a little while they stretch and need to be readjusted. Can you provide an image of the brake calipers on the bike for better answers?

Comment: Maybe? We have no idea what kind of brakes are on your huffy.

Comment: The pads in your picture are for old-fashioned caliper/sidepull brakes.  It would be a pretty old bike to have that style.  So first [determine which style you have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_brake#Types_of_rim_brakes).  After that, you need to understand how to adjust the brakes.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good site with basic instructions.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you need to confirm the material of your wheel. If your wheels are carbon fiber, you need to use the professional brake pads made of cork which are normally labelled as "use for carbon rims".

If your wheels are aluiminium/alloy or steel, use pads made of rubber.

Secondly you need to confirm the brake type of your wheels. The mountings for V brake pads and caliper brake pads are different.

Your photo shows pads for an older bike with caliper brakes.

Please take a picture of your brake and add it to the question.

Comment: I've tidied your answer.  If I have changed anything that affects the meaning, please use revert, or re-edit it.

Comment: He said "Huffy".  They may make a model with a carbon fork or some such, but I seriously doubt that they make anything with carbon rims.